# About FAT-32 File System

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I have two questions about FAT-32 file system.

With the FAT-32 File System introduced in wiki, and from the structure provided as following: [image][image]

, 
each file can have name with length no larger than 8?

What's more, I found that the data of the first file I create is as expected to be at cluster #3. (Since root directory begin at cluster #2)

So, does this mean root directory can only store metadata about 16 files? (each occupies 32 bytes in root directory...)
Or, root directory can also get 'fragmented' and each fragments get linked by through information in FAT?

Sorry for my bad formatting.... And thanks for all help.

Comment: I have found the result about file-name length limit on wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits), which prove my guess to be right. But I still have no idea about root directory file number limit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FAT-32 a file can have two filenames. One is always an olde-style 8+3 file name. The other optional file name can have up to 255 characters. A system that supports long file names creates a unique 8+3 file name based on the long name. That allowed even older systems that only supported 8+3 file names to access FAT-32 file systems.

Comment: Then, how about limit of the number of file in root directory?

Comment: There is no limit to the number of files in the root folder in FAT-32. There is in FAT-16.